# Counting the number of raster pixels within shapefile polygon using GeoPandas

Tags: shapefile, polygon, geopandas, zonal-statistics, pixel

I have a shapefile that I have loaded as a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame, and it has a geometry column containing polygons and multipolygons.

My end goal is to do some zonal computations on a GeoTiff raster, in particular, I want to compute the mean value within each polygon, and also count the number of pixels that contributed to that polygon's zonal mean. Here's a link to [another GIS-SE question of mine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149031/zonal-computations-computing-raster-pixel-counts-within-polygons-using-gdal-ver) that outlines my attempts to do that so far using GDAL and rasterstats.

I am just wondering if GeoPandas is up to zonal calculations yet. If I open a raster in GDAL/numpy/rasterio and load the shapefile in a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame, is there a way to compute the number of raster pixels inside each polygon?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'count the number of pixels'?

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to GIS and wasn't thinking straight. Obviously the shapefile doesn't have pixels, I was thinking of the GeoTiff raster I want to overlay. I'll delete this question

Comment: So you are looking for the number of pixels in the raster within each polygon? You can edit your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do zonal statistics from a GeoDataFrame directly on a GeoTiff using [rasterstats](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats).

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

geodf = gpd.read_file("foo.shp")
zonal_stats(geodf, "bar.tif")
```

There are some good examples of rasterstats integration on [the wiki](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/wiki/Notebooks).

Comment: Yes - I did go with rasterstats in the end and it works great.

Comment: do these stats reflect the values of the pixels? or their area?

Comment: @fccoelho Zonal statistics are descriptive statistics (mean, median, min, max, etc) of the set of pixels which intersect a geometry. Thus both the number of pixels (roughly equivalent to the area of the geometry) and the value of those pixels are considered.

Answer (score 0):

By "count the number of pixels" do mean the area of each polygon? If so,

```
mygeodf.area
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question didn't make any sense, so I've updated it.